# Discord.py Massdm

Tags: python, discord.py

i need this Mass Dm to message everyone except the author
But i dont really know how to do it...

```
@bot.command()
    async def massdm(self, ctx, *, args=None):
        if args != None:
            members = ctx.guild.members
            for member in members:
                try:
                    await member.send(args)
                    print("'" + args + "' sent to: " + member.name)

                except:
                    print("Couldn't send '" + args + "' to: " + member.name)

        else:
            await ctx.channel.send("A message was not provided.")
```

Comment: Code seems okay, is there any error?

Comment: No there isnt any Error, but i need it to dm everyone except the author

Comment: What is your discord.py version?

Comment: Newest, I just Updated it 3 Days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new version of discord.py(1.5.x), there're some changes about `Intents`. Intents are like permissions, you need to define it to use some of the things like sending private messages. You have to define it before the `bot = discord.Bot()`.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = discord.Bot(prefix='', intents=intents)
```

If you just want to enable to sending private messages, you can do `intents = discord.Intents().dm_messages` but I suggest you to use `discord.Intents().all()`.

For more information, you can look at the [API references](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def massdm(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    for member in list(client.get_all_members()):
        try:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Test",
                                  description="Test!",
                                  color=discord.Colour.blurple())
            embed.set_thumbnail(
                url="test")
            embed.set_footer(
                text=
                "test"
            )
            await asyncio.sleep(30)
            await member.send(embed=embed)
        except:
            pass
        #await ctx.send(f"Messaged: {member.name}")
        print(f"Messaged: {member.name}")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).